# Excel VBA pivot function works when stepped-through but not when run

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to set up a couple simple buttons to filter multiple pivots on multiple sheets within a workbook. Nothing fancy here! The pivots do not share a common source, so slicers won't work for me.  But all share a common field name that I want to filter.
My code works if I step through it (F8) but if I try to run it straight through (F5) I get an error of "Code execution has been interrupted" and the debugger highlights the first Next.  If I comment out the line which modifies the filter, the function runs fine regardless of which way I do it. Help please?

```
Sub troubleshoot()

Dim wks As Worksheet, strName As String, pvt As PivotTable, strPvtName As String

For Each wks In Worksheets
     strName = wks.Name
        For Each pvt In wks.PivotTables
        strPvtName = pvt.Name
        Debug.Print strName + " / " + strPvtName
        Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType").ClearAllFilters
    Next
Next

Set wks = Nothing
Set pvt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have your tried using `FOR i` & `FOR j` instead of 2 `FOR EACH`? Sometimes FOR EACH stop working inside the loop when you modify the referenced object or content

Comment: By the way, this line `Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType").ClearAllFilters` could be replaced by `pvt.PivotFields("OrderSubType").ClearAllFilters` since you already have a reference to the PivotTable object

Comment: Good point on shortening the line.  I've had that at some point but keep changing things around as I'm trying to troubleshoot.

Re: your other suggestion to use i & j, I need to do something like 
`For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`
for the first loop, right?  But I haven't been able to come up with the right way to get a similar count of the pivot tables in the given spreadsheet to use for j on the second loop? I know just enough VBA to get myself in trouble...

Comment: OK - correction. I can get the count, I now just can't get it all put together correctly...

Comment: Seems the error wasn't caused specifically by my code. I got the same error when doing a recorded macro of all the same steps my function was intended to do. Apparently it's a bit of a bug. The solution is to switch to the VBE window, do Ctrl+Break/Pause. Close the VBE window, OK that it will end the debugger.  Then go back to the spreadsheet and run the macro - no error.  Odd, but working now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go through all pivot table and clear all filters on "**OrderSubType**" field (When this field exists) using 2 FOR LOOP. I Also have put some error handling.

```
Public Sub troubleshoot()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo EndOfSub

    Dim wks As Worksheet, pvt As PivotTable, pvts As PivotTables
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
         Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
         Set pvts = wks.PivotTables 'GET PIVOTTABLES COLLECTION
         For j = 1 To pvts.Count
            Set pvt = pvts(j)
            Debug.Print wks.Name + " / " + pvt.Name
            If PivotContainsField(pvt, "OrderSubType") Then
                pvt.PivotFields("OrderSubType").ClearAllFilters 'CLEAR FILTERS
            Else
                Debug.Print "OrderSubType field not found in : " + pvt.Name
            End If
         Next j
    Next i

    Set wks = Nothing
    Set pvt = Nothing

EndOfSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub

Public Function PivotContainsField(pvt As PivotTable, fieldName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
    pvt.PivotFields (fieldName)
    PivotContainsField = (Err.Number = 0)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```